# how to use offline location in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, maps

I want to add the location of my office in my flutter app when the user downloads my app  can show my office location saved at app without using the internet (offline location).
It is possible to do this in  flutter? If yes, how can I integrate my office location in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can statically add location - latitude and longitude and other required parameter.

```
  LatLng? _currentPosition;

_currentPosition = LatLng(
           37.0902 //yourLocatiionLatitude,
           95.7129 //yourLocatiionLongitude
)
```

Use this _currentPosition variable in your location default position

Comment: don't understand can you provide me some code

Comment: I update my answer, please check